# Magento price filter

Tags: magento-1.8, price, filter

[image: price filter : my price are from 191 to 900 but in price filter currently shopping by it is showing Rs.191.00 - Rs 899.99 i want the exact price like 191 - 900 kindly help me to solve the issue]

my price are from 191 to 900 but in price filter currently shopping by it is showing  Rs.191.00 - Rs 899.99 i want the exact price like 191 - 900 kindly help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the default functionality of magento:

Still you can change by doing the following:

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php

command the line number  213:-
$toPrice -= .01;

CHANGE TO

//$toPrice -= .01;

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php

change the line number  416:-

$select->where($priceExpr . ' < ' . $this->_getComparingValue($to, $filter));

CHANGE The code like:

$select->where($priceExpr . ' <= ' . $to);